# How to add code inside FCMPlugin.onNotification method Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to Cordova and Ionic.I am currently working on a project which require to include push notifications using firebase.So I followed all turorials available and included FCM plugin successfully.https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

Push notifications are working well.When the app is closed the appear in the message bar with cordova default icon.When app is running the alert message appear as expected.

this is the  code I used in my home.ts file.

```js
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    if(data.wasTapped){
   
      alert( JSON.stringify(data.message) );
    
   }else{
   
     alert( JSON.stringify(data.message) );
     
   
   }
});
```

Whenever I send a push notification from firebase console with the key as message(advanced options) this works as expected.

Now I want to add some action after the alert message(or without alert message)like redirect to a page.

an example given below.

```js
FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(data){
    if(data.wasTapped){
    
      alert( JSON.stringify(data.message) );
    
   }else{
 
     
   this.navCtrl.push(UsersDetailPage);
   }
});
```

In above code want to redirect user to UserDetailPage if an alert message with message key came.

But this doesn't work.
I cannot find any mistake here.May be this is not the correct way of doing the thing .I am very grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

as the "function(data)" change the scope, wrap the code in an arrow function:

```
FCMPlugin.onNotification(
    (data)=>{
        if(data.wasTapped){
        alert( JSON.stringify(data.message) );
    } else {     
        this.navCtrl.push(UsersDetailPage);
   }
});
```

Hope this help you.
Emanuele